# anyone can post an RXJS example using node.js for querying postgresql db?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rxjs

anyone can post an RXJS example using node.js for querying postgresql db?

google doesn't seem to have anything about this...

regards

Sean.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to achieve. RxJs is not about querying databases. Are you rather looking for a postgresql driver for node.js? I am using this one : https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres. From there, read the docs, it should be pretty straightforward how to query the database. Then you can get the result in an observable with `Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback` (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromnodecallback.md). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: well, it can be used for streaming anything, and I was wondering if people use it to query DB as well.. seems logical as it's async and collection based...

Answer (score 2):

voilà!

```
var Rx = require('rx');
var pg = require('pg');


var rowObservable = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var pgClient = new pg.Client();
    pgClient.connect();

    var pgQuery = pgClient.query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;");
    pgQuery.on('error', observer.onError.bind(observer));
    pgQuery.on('row', observer.onNext.bind(observer));
    pgQuery.on('end', observer.onCompleted.bind(observer));

    return pgClient.end.bind(pgClient);
});


var subscription = rowObservable.subscribe(function(row) {
    console.log(row);
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
}, function() {
    subscription.dispose();
});
```

In this example, the client connection `pgClient` is closed when the subscription is disposed. The rest is pretty self explanatory i think :-)